# why is a, b = b, a not working as the way it should be when a, b are subarrays with different lengths?

Tags: python, list, swap, sublist

As a newbie to Python, I understand `a, b = b, a` in python as a simple swap, but why does it not behave as I expected when `a` and `b` are two subarrays with different lengths?

For example:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

nums[0:4], nums[4:] = nums[4:], nums[0:4]

print(nums)  #[5, 6, 7, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why there's a duplicated 5 after 7? Why is it not [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4] since I just divided `nums` into 2 subarrays and swapped their order?

Thanks!

Comment: aren't you replacing nums[0:4] which has 4 elements with nums[4:] which has 3?

Comment: Yes, I understand this but I'm just confused about how it works when we swap arrays with different lengths. @user2357112 explained it in a detailed and clear way, which can be found down below. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thinking of `a, b = b, a` as a swap breaks down when you're working with more complicated expressions than just variables.

When evaluating `nums[0:4], nums[4:] = nums[4:], nums[0:4]`, Python starts with the RHS, which evaluates to `([5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4])`.

Then it assigns `[5, 6, 7]` to `nums[0:4]`. This replaces the first 4 elements of `nums` with the elements of the `[5, 6, 7]` list, producing

```
[5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7]
```

Then it assigns `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to `nums[4:]`. `nums[4:]` is not the last 3 elements, because the first assignment changed the size of the list. `nums[4:]` is now only the last *two* elements. Python replaces the last two elements of `nums` with `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, producing

```
[5, 6, 7, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very clear, and actually far simpler than what I imagined.

Comment: Thank you!! Your explanation is very clear and finally I understand how python works behind the scene for this line of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around and it works:

```
nums[4:], nums[0:4] = nums[0:4], nums[4:]

# nums is [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Eduardo Motta de Moraes! Yes, it works, but I'm just confused how it works when we swap arrays with different lengths.